# JSTL not parsed in a JSP page running on an embedded Jetty instance

Tags: java, servlets, maven, jetty, jstl

I have a web application which works fine if i just deploy it on to the deploy folder of either Tomcat or Jboss. What i am trying to do now is to embed this application on to a Jetty container. I cant seem to get it to work as it is spitting out errors related to the JSTL tag library. Here is the error that is shown:

```
Problem accessing /Web/app/localTimestamp. Reason:

    /WEB-INF/views/localTimestamp.jsp(1,62) PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Caused by:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/localTimestamp.jsp(1,62) PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:172)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTLDLocation(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:431)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:240)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:502)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:582)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1652)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:185)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:145)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:212)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:537)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:98)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1157)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:927)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I dont understand why it is not able to pick up the jstl jar file. Here are the jar files in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the web application

```
   19/06/2012  14:54            62,983 activation-1.1.jar
   19/06/2012  14:53             4,467 aopalliance-1.0.jar
   19/06/2012  14:57            59,590 commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
   19/06/2012  14:57           163,151 commons-io-2.1.jar
   19/06/2012  14:54           207,723 commons-lang-2.1.jar
   19/06/2012  14:53            60,686 commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
   19/06/2012  14:54           104,172 jaxb-api-2.2.jar
   19/06/2012  14:54           872,831 jaxb-impl-2.2.jar
   19/06/2012  14:57           414,240 jstl-1.2.jar
   19/06/2012  14:53           367,444 log4j-1.2.14.jar
   19/06/2012  14:53            17,384 slf4j-api-1.5.2.jar
   19/06/2012  14:53             9,501 slf4j-log4j12-1.5.2.jar
   19/06/2012  14:53           331,474 spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
   19/06/2012  14:53            53,079 spring-asm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
   19/06/2012  14:53           589,253 spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
   19/06/2012  14:53           829,601 spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
   19/06/2012  14:53           106,819 spring-context-support-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
   19/06/2012  14:53           442,400 spring-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
   19/06/2012  14:53           176,283 spring-expression-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
   19/06/2012  15:04            61,379 spring-oxm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
   19/06/2012  14:53           246,036 spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
   19/06/2012  14:53           540,819 spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
   19/06/2012  14:53           572,266 spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
   19/06/2012  14:56           493,742 spring-ws-core-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar
   19/06/2012  14:56            92,942 spring-xml-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar
   19/06/2012  14:54            23,346 stax-api-1.0-2.jar
   19/06/2012  14:56           148,522 wsdl4j-1.6.1.jar
   19/06/2012  14:54         1,229,125 xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
   19/06/2012  14:55           109,318 xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
```

And these are the libraries that are included in the Jetty starter application:

```
16/07/2012  17:35           117,444 javax.el-2.2.3.jar
16/07/2012  17:35            38,863 javax.el-api-2.2.4.jar
16/07/2012  17:35           545,240 javax.servlet.jsp-2.2.3.jar
16/07/2012  17:35            53,124 javax.servlet.jsp-api-2.2.1.jar
16/07/2012  14:03            21,212 jetty-continuation-8.1.0.RC5.jar
16/07/2012  14:03            93,383 jetty-http-8.1.0.RC5.jar
16/07/2012  14:03           101,433 jetty-io-8.1.0.RC5.jar
16/07/2012  14:03            86,238 jetty-security-8.1.0.RC5.jar
16/07/2012  14:03           330,266 jetty-server-8.1.0.RC5.jar
16/07/2012  14:03            95,359 jetty-servlet-8.1.0.RC5.jar
16/07/2012  14:03           268,069 jetty-util-8.1.0.RC5.jar
16/07/2012  14:03           106,926 jetty-webapp-8.1.0.RC5.jar
16/07/2012  14:03            37,919 jetty-xml-8.1.0.RC5.jar
19/06/2012  14:57           414,240 jstl-1.2.jar
19/06/2012  14:53           367,444 log4j-1.2.14.jar
17/07/2012  09:42             6,300 WebJettyServices-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
16/07/2012  14:03           210,354 servlet-api-3.0.20100224.jar
              17 File(s)      2,893,814 bytes
```

I think the error is probably due to a conflict in the jar files. I have tried the following with no success

- Rebuilt the war file without the jstl dependency
- Rebuilt the Jetty Starter app without the jstl dependency.
- Rebuilt both without the jstl dependencies

I am now stuck as i dont know how else to test. Here are the relevant code snippets. Here is the Maven pom file for the Jetty starter application. One big problem i found is that it is very difficult to really know which dependencies are required to get this to work. search.maven.com seem to not have all the jar files required by the org.eclipse.* dependencies.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>WebClient</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.mypackage</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.mypackage</groupId>
  <artifactId>WebJettyServices</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>WebJettyServices</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jetty.version>8.1.0.RC5</jetty.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.14</log4j.version>
    <glassfish.javax.version>2.2.3</glassfish.javax.version>
    <glassfish.javax-impl.version>2.2</glassfish.javax-impl.version>
    <glassfish.javax-jstl.version>1.2.1</glassfish.javax-jstl.version>
    <glassfish.jstl.version>1.2</glassfish.jstl.version>


  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

   <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-all-server</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.0.RC5</version>
        </dependency>

         Jetty Webapp -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSP Support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp</artifactId>
        <version>${glassfish.javax.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- EL Support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>${glassfish.javax.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL Support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${glassfish.jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>    
  </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.mypackage.jetty.WebStarter</mainClass>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>                     
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>  
    </build>
</project>
```

### Edit

Here is the JSP page in question

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html 
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/styles/btmsm.css"/>"
    type="text/css" />
<title>Local Timestamp</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container" style="width: 800px">

        <div id="header" style="background-color: #EEEEBB;">
            <h1 style="margin-bottom: 0;">Local timestamp</h1>
        </div>  

        <div id="content"
            style="background-color: #EEEEEE; height: 200px; width: 650px; float: left;">
            The local time is ${localTime}          
        </div>  
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

And the web app version shown in the web.xml file

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
        version="2.4">
```

The application does work if i deploy the war file directly onto the Tomcat or Jboss deployment folder. It is only a problem when embedded with Jetty.

Answer (score 1):

The problem should be that you declared your application with web-app 2.4 in your web.xml, please replace it with 2.5 or higher, this problem should be solved.

replace this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
        version="2.4">
```

with:

```
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="YourWebAppID"
    version="2.5">
```

please feed back.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your jsp is a problem?
Could you please post the JSP part where you're importing the JSTL.
This should be compliant with the web version you're using (see in web.xml) - so please post the relevant part here as well.

Maybe its just a matter of path or something?

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks - I have posted the JSP page and the web app version defined in the web.xml file